# Как задать последовательность выбора виджетов при нажатии Tab

Tags: c++, qt

Есть окно QDialog, в котором имеются виджеты QLineEdit, QComboBox, QSpinBox и т.д. Посколько в редакторе форм я их создавал в произвольном поряде, а потом расставлял так как мне нужно, то при переходе от одного элементиа к другому посредством нажатии клавиши Tab обход виджетов происходит не в порядке сверху вниз и слева направо, а в том порядке, в котором я добавлял эти элементы(т.е. может прыгать по диагонали, снизу вверх и т.п.). Как изменить порядок обхода?

Comment: Qt Designer - Правка - Изменение порядка переключений (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-tab-order.html)

Comment: goldstar_labs а как это сделать с помощью кода?

Comment: goldstar_labs в любом случае оставляйте ответ, помечу его как решение

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder

Comment: goldstar_labs Да и ещё вопрос. Каким образом включить в этот порядок кнопки Ок и Cancel

Comment: Кнопки Ок и Кансел чего? по умолчанию вроде QT не создает таких

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65820/discussion-between-goldstar-labs-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Qt Designer'a:
Меню - Правка - Изменение порядка переключений (Menu - Edit - Edit Tab Order)

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-tab-order.html

Из кода:
статическая функция `void QWidget::setTabOrder(QWidget *first, QWidget *second)`
first - виджет, который имеет фокус
second - виджет, на который будет переключен фокус с first

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder

Comment: важно помнить, чтобы цепочка переключений фокуса строилась непрерывно, это описано по второй ссылке более подробно.